# displaying pirvate post in single template wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications, view, runtime-error

please hep to pin point the problem in the following code

```
function contest_adjust_query($query){

    if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('contest') AND $query->is_main_query()) {
        
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'private'));

    }

    if (!is_admin() AND $query->is_main_query() AND is_user_logged_in() AND is_singular( 'contest' )) {

        $query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'private'));

    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'contest_adjust_query');
```

error output top of page
Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\contest\wp-includes\class-wp-query.php on line 4196

Comment: i think is_singular( 'contest' ) is problematic adding this created problem

Comment: I don’t think you can use `is_singular` before the query has actually run. Try [`get_queried_object`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) perhaps, and check what _type_ the returned object is.

Comment: Thanks for reply 1. i think get_queried_object is very big thing for such small task 2. why is_post_type_archive('contest') works? but not is_singular( 'contest' )